# XAMARIN - java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

After Migrate my Xamarin Android app with AndroidX. This error is coming.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, com/google/android/gms/actions/ItemListIntents.class   PROJECT.Android
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same error with "ReserveIntents.class". A rebuild of my project solved the issue.

Comment: Yesterday I did several cleanups and rebuilds, but the problem remained.
I rebuild today for the first time, and the issue was fixed. Thanks  @Christian